# Dealing with timedate features in a dataframe in machine learning algorithms

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a data frame of the following features:

```
['plug-in time', 'plug-out time', 'charging duration','charge value']
```

for instance `'plug-in time'` is of the date format (i.e. `2020/12/31 18:32:19`) and similarly for other time-date features.

I am trying to use a learning-based method for this dataset, however, I have set up a function that automatically converts `pandas object` features (e.g `'plug-in time', 'plug-out time', 'charging duration'`) into integers using the following codes:

```
df['plug-in time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['plug-in time'])

for row in df['plug-in time']:
  
      df['plug-in time'][row] = 3600*df['plug-in time'][row].hour+60*df['plug-in time'][row].minute+df['plug-in time'][row].second
```

So that my data in the feature `['plug-in time']` becomes integers with the resolution of seconds (so that `2020/12/31 18:32:19` becomes `an integer`).

Then I use the values in my prediction models. This sounds a bit silly, but this is what I do to tackle the error around attributes and argument types I get when using learning methods.

Is there any other way around this?

I know that `sklearn` has classes for data preprocessing, but I am not sure those preprocessing are useful for `timestamp` features (like `pandas timestamp`).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the final charge value is related to the starting charging value more than anything else.  ie, the charging efficiency is greatest when the battery is very low.  Since you don't know the starting charge value, you would most likely use the day of the week and hour of the day as a proxy.  One hypothesis could be that plugging the phone in late on a weekday night the battery would be lower than early in the morning or on weekends.

I suspect you can drop the plug-out time as it's rendered irrelevant w/the duration feature.  You can one hot encode your weekday feature.  Remember that the day and hour are ordinal features, not continuous - this is kind of important.

My guess is given the features you have, this is a pretty good starting point.

In any case you could use

```
df['day_of_week'] = df['plug-in time'].dt.weekday_name
df['hour_of_day'] = df['plug-in time'].dt.hour
df.drop(columns=['plug-in time','plug-out time'], inplace=True)
```

Here's a [good link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311494/best-practice-for-encoding-datetime-in-machine-learning) on how to handle the hour of day, and don't forget to one-hot encode (make dummies) for your weekday feature.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Good guess around the subject of the matter. But, this is actually the dataset associated with electric vehicles arriving and charging at the station. The dataset has many features and those mentioned were just a few.

What I am looking for is how to work with timestamp features. Let's say I want to use a classification method based on different features. How can I do that considering such features in my dataset?

Comment: Gotcha, hopefully the answer gives you some ideas.  From the sound of it perhaps charge value is the cost of the charge session.  In any case you can repeat the same treatment to both the start and stop times and achieve what you are looking for I hope.